# Need support with JButton events

Tags: java, swing

I've recently had a question answered about how to open a login panel in my main method in another class.
Because i have not yet had any lessons in Swing yet (only basic Java Programming) i have already stumbled upon another question.

How can i detect if a user has pressed a button in the JPanel and make it do something.

For example:
User pressed login -> if (textfield1.getText() == "user"){ open another JFrame } -> etc.

Here is my main code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Corendon {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
           showLogin();
    }

    private static void showLogin(){
        Login login = new Login();

        JFrame loginFrame = new JFrame();
        loginFrame.add(login);
        loginFrame.pack();
        loginFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        loginFrame.setVisible(true);
        loginFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
}
```

Here is the Login class:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Daan
 */
public class Login extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    /**
     * Creates new form Login
     */
    public Login() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNINGds: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPasswordField1 = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Daan\\Dropbox\\HvA\\Programming\\Corendon\\corendon.png")); // NOI18N

        jLabel2.setText("Username");

        jLabel3.setText("Password");

        jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Dutch", "English" }));

        jButton1.setText("Login");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("Cancel");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(45, 45, 45)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                            .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(14, 14, 14)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                                .addComponent(jButton2)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jButton1))
                            .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 214, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 214, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                .addContainerGap(22, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(16, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                    .addComponent(jButton1))
                .addGap(35, 35, 35))
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    }                                        

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   


}
```

So i tried working inside the Login.java and use the private method which is an event-handler. I made it something like:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String user = jTextField1.getText();
    if(user == "user")  {
         jTextField1.setText("LOL");
    }
}
```

Just to test if it actually even did what i wanted, but when i pressed the button it didn't do anything. After that i tried working it out in my main.java where i actually created the frame with the JPanel in it. After reading alot of tutorials, which always created the JPanel and JButton etc. all in the same java file (which is in my case the main.java).

So how do i detect if the login button was pressed, and then make it dispose of the JFrame and move on to another Method in which i create another JFrame with information in it.

I hope i am clear enough, if not please let me know.

EDIT:
When i changed the test code to: user.equals("user") it did work. But now i need it to dispose the Login frame and access another method in my main.java. How can i achieve this from inside a private method in the Login.java?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: `if(user == "user")` dont compare value of Strings with `==` but with `equals` method like `if(user.equals("user"))` or even better to prevent NPE if `user` would be `null` start from String literal like `if("user".equals(user))`.

Comment: Did you try with: "if(user.equals("user"))" in event handler?

Comment: Oh snap, you are right about that part i should have known. I will edit right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But now i need it to dispose the Login frame and access another method
>   in my main.java. How can i achieve this from inside a private method
>   in the Login.java?

Here you have a design problem. You cannot call any frame's method because your `ActionListener` has its scope limited to `Login` panel. How to solve this? Implementing an `ActionListener` that has *visibility*  enough to dispose the frame.

**Note:** try to avoid NetBeans GUI Builder (or any GUI builder). It's easy but you miss a lot of things than making it by your own hand. You can even write a cleaner code. But it's necessary learn about [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Example of Code: this example illustrates the fact that you can achieve the same with less than half of lines of code.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Demo {    

    private void initGUI(){        

        final JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Login");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);        

        JButton button = new JButton("Accept");        
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if("user".equals(textField.getText())){
                    frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
                    // or simply frame.dispose()
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong user! Keep trying.", "Login failed", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        });

        JPanel login = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        login.add(new JLabel("User"));
        login.add(textField);
        login.add(button);

        frame.getContentPane().add(login);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }    

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Demo().initGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I've never seen someone Specify an ActionListener for a button quite like that before.. 
Typically you will do one of two things (AFAIK):

Implement the  `ActionListener` in the class that contains the  `JButton` you wish to use, then  `JButton.addActionListener(this)` to tell the button to use this class as an ActionListener.  Your  `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` method will do what you want the button to do.

OR

Create a new class that implements the `ActionListener` class and add it as an actionListener to the JButton.

Example:

```
public class Example1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JButton button1;
    JTextField field1;

    public Example1()
    {
        super();
        button1 = new JButton("Login");
        button1.addActionListener(this);

        field1 = new JTextField();

        add(button1);
        add(field1);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Login")) //for use with multiple buttons, there are other ways to do this
            field1.setText("LOL");
    }

}
```

I think this is what you were looking for..

Comment: An anonymous inner class for `ActionListeners` is the idiomatic Java approach. Making the containing class implement `ActionListener` and passing `this` is bad design, and the listener may be lightweight enough where a separate named class is unnecessary.