# How to access Jtable created in netbeans UI

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I used the UI builder to create it, I pass it to a method successfully (custom code inside auto generated), but how will I reference to it from another scope? (e.g. from main).

I want to execute this kind of code, but I need the jTable1 in my scope:

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
Object[] obj = jtable_element;
model.addRow(obj);
```

Comment: That's why I hate UI builders for creating a swing application.

Comment: How did you create the `JTable`? As a seperate file? Within a panel/dialog? Hard to help you there without more informations. Usually, if I want to reuse a UI component created with Netbeans, I build that component seperatly from the whole.

Comment: It is auto generated: public class XMLappletUI extends javax.swing.JFrame{
... 
private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
...
} (I can add even more info if it's necessary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that table is a private member of your class.
according to your comment, your class is "XMLappletUI"

in that class, you can add your own methods. just add it below the auto generated code. netbeans will not change your code when it modifes the auto generated code after gui changes.

so for example define a method:

```
public void addRow(){

 DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
 Object[] obj = jtable_element;
 model.addRow(obj);

}
```

now, you can call that method on the class instance.

**EDIT**

if you want to pass a single String argument

```
public void addRow(String jtable_element){

     DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
     Object[] obj = {jtable_element};
     model.addRow(obj);

    }
```

Comment: can you change public void addRow() to public void addRow(String jtable_element)? Then it's fully functional for this case.

Comment: that is just a method. you can pass any parameters to it. you can also define other add methods. I will edit the answer as your comment.

Comment: problem: Object[] obj = jtable_element; In another method it works perfect, in this I get: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Object[]. Declaration in the method that works: String [] jtable_element = {val1, val2, val3};

Comment: UPDATE: i used public static void addRow(String [] jtable_element) but now  DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel(); reports error: non-static variable jTable1 cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: That line "Object[] obj = jtable_elemen" i took from your question and i assumed its an object array.  note in my edit i surrounded it with {} in order to construct an array and initialize it.

Comment: the table is not a static variable. a static method can't access that variable

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40591/discussion-between-a-j-and-user2692669)

Answer (score 1):

> I pass it to a method successfully (custom code inside auto
>   generated), but how will I reference to it from another scope? (e.g.
>   from main).

In order to access this table from another class you'll need to add a getter to this `JTable` since it's a `private` attribute in the class that you have generated using UI builder:

```
public JTable getTable {
    return this.jTable1;
}
```

However my best suggestion would be don't use a GUI builder. Spend some time learning about Swing and write your GUI classes by your own hand. You can even write a cleaner code. For instance see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456935/need-support-with-jbutton-events/19458904#19458904)

Answer (score 0):

**If you need to access this from another class:**

Modify the generated code to expose a method that either:

- Returns the model for you to run this code
- Takes in an object as a parameter and runs this code  (possibly the better of these two options).

**If you need to access this from the same class**, your options are the same as above or you could just save the model off into a variable on the actual class that you could run this code in a separate method.