# Buttons, jFrame, jPanel, I dont have access to methods

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have 2 jPanels in one jFrame, On 1st jPanel (Steiner) I'm drawning graphs, on second B, I have buttons which I added to jPanel on Frame, All actions for buttons are in Frame class, I dont have access to use public method from Steiner. How I can use it ?

```
    package net.kxyz;

   import java.awt.Color;
   import java.awt.Dimension;
   import java.awt.Graphics;
   import java.awt.Graphics2D;
   import java.util.Random;

   /**
    *
    * @author kuman
    */
   public class Steiner extends javax.swing.JPanel {

int minX = 1000, minY = 1000, maxX = 0, maxY = 0;
long temp = 1000;
Graph graph = new Graph(6);
Point[] p = new Point[6];
int hight = 7; // hieight of oval - Point
int width = 7; //  width of oval - Point
int terminals;
Random rand = new Random();
LazyPrimMinimumSpanningTree lazyPrimMST = new LazyPrimMinimumSpanningTree(graph);

/**
 * Creates new form Steiner
 */
public Steiner() {

    graph = setTerminals();
    lazyPrimMST.Find(graph);
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 317, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
}// </editor-fold>

// Variables declaration - do not modify
// End of variables declaration
@Override
public void paint(Graphics x) {
    super.paint(x);

    Dimension d = getSize();


    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) x;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height);
        findSolution();





        for (Edge edge : lazyPrimMST.edges()) {
            // g.setColor(Color.black);

            g.setColor(edge.getPointP().getColor());
            g.fillOval(edge.getPointP().getX(), edge.getPointP().getY(), width, hight);
            g.setColor(edge.getPointN().getColor());
            g.fillOval(edge.getPointN().getX(), edge.getPointN().getY(), width, hight);
            g.drawLine(edge.getPointP().getX(), edge.getPointP().getY() + 4, edge.getPointN().getX(), edge.getPointN().getY() + 4);

        }




    }
}

public void findMinMax(Point p, Point n) {
    //code

}

public void findSolution() {
      //code

    }
}
```

Frame

```
    /*
     * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    package net.kxyz;

    /**
             *
     * @author kuman
     */
    public class Ramka extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form Ramka
 */
public Ramka() {
    Steiner steiner;
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    steiner1 = new net.kxyz.Steiner();
    b1 = new net.kxyz.B();
    bRandom = new javax.swing.JButton();
    bStart = new javax.swing.JButton();
    valueOfTerminals = new javax.swing.JSpinner();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    valueOfGeneration = new javax.swing.JSpinner();
    valueOfLimfocits = new javax.swing.JSpinner();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    textPanel = new javax.swing.JTextPane();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout steiner1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(steiner1);
    steiner1.setLayout(steiner1Layout);
    steiner1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        steiner1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    steiner1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        steiner1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 251, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    bRandom.setText("Losuj");
    bRandom.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            bRandomActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    bStart.setText("Start");
    bStart.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            bStartActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    valueOfTerminals.addPropertyChangeListener(new java.beans.PropertyChangeListener() {
        public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            valueOfTerminalsPropertyChange(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel1.setText("Liczba terminali:");

    jLabel2.setText("Liczba generacji:");

    jLabel3.setText("Liczba limfocytów:");

    jScrollPane2.setViewportView(textPanel);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout b1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(b1);
    b1.setLayout(b1Layout);
    b1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        b1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(b1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(b1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(jLabel3))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(b1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addGroup(b1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(valueOfLimfocits, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(bStart, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(b1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(valueOfTerminals, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(bRandom, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 82, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addComponent(valueOfGeneration, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 165, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGap(11, 11, 11))
    );
    b1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        b1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(b1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(b1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2)
                .addGroup(b1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(b1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(bRandom)
                        .addComponent(valueOfTerminals, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(b1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(valueOfGeneration, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(b1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(valueOfLimfocits, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addComponent(bStart)))))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(steiner1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addComponent(b1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(steiner1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(b1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

private void bStartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    findSolution(); //doesnt work (?)
}

private void valueOfTerminalsPropertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:



}

private void bRandomActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    findSolution();

}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /*
     * Set the Nimbus look and feel
     */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /*
     * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
     * default look and feel. For details see
     * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Ramka.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Ramka.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Ramka.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Ramka.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /*
     * Create and display the form
     */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Ramka().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private net.kxyz.B b1;
private javax.swing.JButton bRandom;
private javax.swing.JButton bStart;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
private net.kxyz.Steiner steiner1;
private javax.swing.JTextPane textPanel;
private javax.swing.JSpinner valueOfGeneration;
private javax.swing.JSpinner valueOfLimfocits;
private javax.swing.JSpinner valueOfTerminals;
// End of variables declaration
    }
```

B

```
    package net.kxyz;


    public class B extends javax.swing.JPanel {

/**
 * Creates new form B
 */
public B() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    jButton1.setText("jButton1");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(22, 22, 22)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(305, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(30, 30, 30)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(247, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
}// </editor-fold>

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    findSoluton();   // doesnt work too (?)     // TODO add your handling code here:
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
// End of variables declaration
    }
```

Comment: *I dont have access to use public method from Steiner*. What does it mean exactly? You may want to take a look to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19458904/1795530) to a similar scope related problem. Also you shouldn't override `paint()` method but `paintComponent()` instead: [A Closer Look at the Paint Mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the Steiner instance into your B instance and then allow B to call public methods on Steiner.

e.g.,

B.java (terrible class name by the way):

```
public class B {
  private Steiner steiner;

  public B(Steiner steiner) {
    this.steiner = steiner;
  }
```

---

Frame.java:

```
steiner1 = new net.kxyz.Steiner();
b1 = new net.kxyz.B(steiner1);  // ***** note the change
```

---

Other comments about your code:

- Override a JPanel's paintComponent method, not its paint method.
- You shouldn't have a findSolution() method or any logic method within any painting method, either paint or paintComponent as these methods are for painting only.
- I'd rename the B class to something else, perhaps "ButtonPanel".
- I'd rename the Frame class to something else since Frame is already a class name in the standard Java library and your name could confuse others. Try to give it a more specific name.
- Eventually you'll want to separate out the logic part of your program completely from the GUI portion a la MVC or one of its many variants.
- I would have one of your buttons call findSolution() and have this method do your calculations, but not be involved in drawing anything (and again not be part of your paint or paintComponent method). Then when findSolution() is done, call repaint so that the data can be displayed in the paintComponent method.
- Note that if findSolution takes significant time to complete (anything more than say 100-200 ms), you'll want to run it in a background thread such as in a SwingWorker.
- Soon you'll learn about cohesion and coupling, and you will avoid using direct solutions like I've posted. Instead you will make use of interfaces to loosen the coupling of your program and increase its cohesion. But for now, you just might want to read up on these concepts as well as dependency injection just to be familiar with what they are.

Comment: +1 for *terrible class name*. BTW *Frame* is not a good choice either :)

Comment: sorry for class name, it was for a moment.
Program work with this solution. BIG thanks